# node js get value from key

Tags: node.js, json, discord.js, key

i need help i am trying to retrieve the value '802125586923257886' from my json file what can i do?

```
{
  "801502579829112852": {
    "channel": "802125586923257886"
  },
  "802163006698946570": {
    "channel": "802163007173951521"
  }
}
```

I tried this but it doesn't end

```
function jsonParser(stringValue) {
  var string = JSON.stringify(stringValue);
  var objectValue = JSON.parse(string);
}

console.log(jsonParser('801502579829112852'))
```

thank you in advance

Comment: Where do you read the file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are trying to do is lookup a value from a key which is in turn again the value to another key in a JSON dictionary using Javascript.

You need to save the JSON string into a variable and parse that into a Javascript Dictionary:

```
json_dict = `{
  "801502579829112852": {
    "channel": "802125586923257886"
  },
  "802163006698946570": {
    "channel": "802163007173951521"
  }
}`

js_dict = JSON.parse(json_dict)
```

Then, you can access the fields of your Javascript dictionary:

```
js_dict["801502579829112852"]["channel"]
```

which returns:

```
802125586923257886
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
// Your value is already in JSON format. No need to parse again
var json_dict = {
  "801502579829112852": {
    "channel": "802125586923257886"
  },
  "802163006698946570": {
    "channel": "802163007173951521"
  }
}

jsonParser(json_dict)

function jsonParser (pvalue){
  var chanldataobj = pvalue['801502579829112852']
  console.log(chanldataobj['channel'])
}
```